# add and remove dynamic array in angular 8

Tags: arrays, dynamic, angular8

i am working with dyanmic array.. i have a model class .. this i have assign ass array.. but when i bind getting error like ngFor can only iterate array.. Cant identify where i went wrong.. can anybody help me?
Model.ts

```
export class AddDriver {
  constructor(
    public additionalDriverId: string,
    public additionalDriverName: string,
    public IDNumber: string,
    public dob: NgbDate,
    public age: string,
    public gender: string,
    public licenseIssuedDate: NgbDate,
    public licenseExpiryDate: NgbDate,
    public issuedCountry: string,
    public nationality: string,
    public relationship: string
  ) {}
}
 component.ts
addDriverArray: Array<AddDriver> = [];
  newDynamic: any = [];
 this.newDynamic = [{
        additionalDriverId: '', additionalDriverName: '', IDNumber: '', dob: '', age: '', gender: '', licenseIssuedDate: '', licenseExpiryDate: '', issuedCountry: '',
        nationality: '', relationship: ''
      }];
      this.addDriverArray.push(this.newDynamic);
```